# How to find the nearest point to the line?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a point cloud stored as a numpy array. 
There is also a line coming through that point cloud specified with two points.

How can I get the closest point to that line in the most optimized version ?

I have calculated distance to every point one by one, but it takes to much time to calculate that and it freezes my app....

Please help me to optimize that ;(

This is how I have been doing it for every point:

```
def isectSphere(self, p0, p1, cpt):

        # normalized ray direction
        r_dir = np.subtract(p0, p1)
        r_dir = r_dir / np.linalg.norm(r_dir)

        # nearest point on the ray to the sphere
        p0_cpt = np.subtract(p0, cpt)
        near_pt = np.subtract(p0, r_dir * np.dot(p0_cpt, r_dir))

        # distance to center point
        return np.linalg.norm(np.subtract(near_pt, cpt))
```

After iterating that code on every point a have been taking the min out of it.

In the point cloud there is around 6 000 000 points.

Comment: How did you calculate the distance to every point? Please provide some code of what you've tried so far so that we can help you more easily :)

Comment: How many points are in the point cloud?

Comment: k-d trees come to mind: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree

Comment: def isectSphere(self, p0, p1, cpt):

        # normalized ray direction
        r_dir = np.subtract(p0, p1)
        r_dir = r_dir / np.linalg.norm(r_dir)

        # nearest point on the ray to the sphere
        p0_cpt = np.subtract(p0, cpt)
        near_pt = np.subtract(p0, r_dir * np.dot(p0_cpt, r_dir))

        # distance to center point
        dist = np.linalg.norm(np.subtract(near_pt, cpt))

Comment: This is how I have calculated it to every point

Comment: In the point cloud there is arount 6 000 000 points

Comment: Also after transforming everything into a linear space (as opposed to a affine space) by deducting the support vector of the line you could project everything  onto the line by a Matrix-Matrix product using a Projection matrix from the spanning vector of the line and a matrix containing all points. Then calculate the differences in the next step. For performance you want to **vectorize every operation** as much as possible.

Comment: what is your point cloud format? is it a Nx3 numpy array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import numpy as np


def isectSphere(p0, p1, cloud):
        """
        >>> isectSphere([1, 0], [3, 0], [[0, -4], [2, 3]])
        1
        >>> isectSphere([1, 0, 0], [3, 0, 0], [[0, -4, 0], [2, 3, 0]])
        1
        """
        p0 = np.asarray(p0)
        p1 = np.asarray(p1)
        cloud = np.asarray(cloud)
        product = np.cross(cloud - p0, p1 - p0)
        if product.ndim == 2:
            distances = np.linalg.norm(product, axis=1)
        else:
            distances = np.abs(product)
        return distances.argmin()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use vectorized calculations:

Assuming `p0` and `p1` are of shape `(m,)` and `pc` is your point cloud array of shape `(N, m)`, you can use `np.cross` to calculate vectorized distance:

```
closest_point = pc[np.argmin(np.linalg.norm(np.cross(p1-p0, p0-pc, axisb=1), axis=1)/np.linalg.norm(p1-p0))]
```

This on a personal system, takes less than a second for over 6,000,000 points.